# Xpath not working on HtmlAgilityPack document

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have a peculiar problem. When I try to apply an Xpath to an `HtmlAgility.HtmlDocument` it doesn't work. But when I take the same document's inner html and create another `HtmlAgility.HtmlDocument` object, the match is found.  Any ideas would really be appreciated.

```
Dim ret As String = Nothing
Dim tmpHtmlNode As HtmlNode = _pageHTML.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(token.MatchingXPath)
If tmpHtmlNode IsNot Nothing AndAlso tmpHtmlNode.InnerText IsNot Nothing Then ' THIS FETCHES NULL'
    ret = tmpHtmlNode.InnerText.Trim
End If

Dim x As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
x.LoadHtml(_pageHTML.DocumentNode.InnerHtml)
Dim node As HtmlNode = Nothing
node = x.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(token.MatchingXPath)
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText) ' THIS WORKS'
```

In the above coce, `tmpHtmlNode` is NULL after evaluation of the XPath. Whereas `node` below return the required text.

Xpath used is `"//*[contains(text(),'Number of Discs:')]/following-sibling::text()"` and the Html portion where the match is expected is:

```
<h2>Product Details</h2>
<div class="content">
  <ul>
    <li><b>Performer:</b> <a href="/s/ref=dp_db_clas_perf?ie=UTF8&amp;keywords=Royal%20Scots%20Dragoon%20Guards&amp;search-alias=classical">Royal Scots Dragoon Guards</a></li>
  <li><b>Audio CD</b>  (March 24, 1992)</li>
  <li><b>Number of Discs:</b> 1</li>
  <li><b>Label:</b> RCA</li>
  <li><b>ASIN:</b> B000002WEN</li>
  <li><b>Average Customer Review:</b>
  <li id="SalesRank">
    <b>Amazon Best Sellers Rank:</b>
    #68,703 in Music (<a href="http://www.amazon.com/best-sellers-music-albums/zgbs/music/ref=pd_dp_ts_m_1">See Top 100 in Music</a>)
  </li>
</ul>
<span class="tiny">
  <ul class="noteBullets">
  </ul>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `InnerHtml` doesn't hold the same HTML markup is the original `HtmlDocument`, check against `OuterHtml` instead. Also, post the failing XPath..

Comment: `OuterHtml` does not work too. Here is the xpath: `//*[contains(text(),'Number of Discs:')]/following-sibling::text()`

Comment: I'd suggest to change the first bit of the XPath to: `//*[contains(.,'Number of Discs:')]`. That's only a guess though, post the relevant portion of the HTML so we can test and see how & why the XPath is failing

Comment: Thx. With `.` atleast I am getting a match on the first path of the XPath `//*[contains(.,'Number of Discs:')]` But the next match `following-sibling::text()` returns an empty string. Html is `<li><b>Number of Discs:</b> 1</li>`

Comment: Also, can you help clarify why text() is not working in this instance?

Comment: Kallol, you are the one who should clarify things. Please edit your question and show all the relevant HTML.

Comment: Mathias, if I could clarify why `text()` is not working as compared to `.`, I wouldn't have asked the question in the first instance. I would edit the question, but I was more seeking help to understand why @har07's response on using `.` works to get at least the node, if not the entire Xpath match.

Comment: Better, now tell us what exactly you'd like to find in that document (again, edit your question to answer).

Comment: @Kallol XPath tester shows that your original XPath worked against HTML snippet posted. So, I almost sure your actual HTML contains different markup from the one posted here. Try to save the `HtmlDocument` to file, then open the file to confirm whether it contains different HTML or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original issue `HtmlDocument` was when a downloaded html was parsed against an XPath, it returned no matches. Whereas when that same html was used to create another `HtmlDocument` and that was parsed with the same XPath, it found the match. Hence the issue is not with the actual XPath as otherwise it would not have worked in the second instance (which is why I didn't post the XPath in the first instance).

Before the call to the code posted in the question, the below code is run to parse another (a different one) field from the same `HtmlDocument`

```
        Dim ret As List(Of String) = Nothing
        Dim tmpHtmlNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = _pageHTML.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(token.MatchingXPath)
        If tmpHtmlNodes IsNot Nothing AndAlso tmpHtmlNodes.Count > 0 Then
            For Each tmpHtmlNode As HtmlNode In tmpHtmlNodesx
                If tmpHtmlNode IsNot Nothing AndAlso tmpHtmlNode.InnerText IsNot Nothing Then
                    If ret Is Nothing Then ret = New List(Of String)
                    ret.Add(tmpHtmlNode.InnerText.Trim)
                    tmpHtmlNode = Nothing
                End If
            Next
        End If
        tmpHtmlNodes.Clear()
        Return ret
```

The parsing logic for this field has the line `tmpHtmlNodes.Clear()` which was the culprit. This changes the `HtmlDocument` and results in the next call for parsing unsuccessful since it is unable to find the node as it was removed by `clear()`.

So summarizing the issue:
1. Before the parsing logic listed in the question above ran, there was another parsing logic that runs which `clears()` nodes that had matched from a `HtmlNodeCollection`
2. This affects the same `HtmlDocument` on which the next parsing logic runs (this is the logic listed in the question)
3. Hence the Xpath fails

Still question is if `_pageHtml` gets changed because of an earlier `HtmlNodeCollection.Clear()` then why would the code where I take the Html from `_pageHtml` and create another `HtmlDocument` and then run the parsing logic on this new `HtmlDocument` work?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
  <b>Number of Discs:</b>
 1
</li>'
```

Maybe this will help

```
//b[contains(text(), 'Number of Discs')]/../text()
```

I think the number "belongs" the to li node, and not the b. Which is why you can't say following-sibling::text()

Comment: Yes, the number is a text node of `li` - which is why `following-sibling::text()` would be perfectly acceptable.